# How to create a template out of a page layout in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, wiki, sharepoint-designer, enterprise

I would like to create a page layout in enterprise wiki where there are different sections with text and pictures, which are not editable by users and between them the users should be able to add text, pictures or else. I would like to use this as a template. Could you help me understand how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this blog post will help you -
http://blog.henryong.com/2010/06/08/how-to-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-page-layouts-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/